# Getting Firebase Listview position

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a User class for populate a listview. This is the way i create User node

```
        currentUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference usersDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    usersDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    User users= new User(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
    String key = currentUser;
    usersDatabase.child(key).setValue(users);
```

[image: Node Image]

All works good... until i want to work with values retrieved from this listview. I set up a way for long click items of listview for get the value, but it doesn't work.

```
@Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                              long id, boolean checked) {
            adminToAdd = new ArrayList<>();
            if (checked) {
                adminToAdd.add(uAdapter.getItem(position));
            } else {
                adminToAdd.remove(uAdapter.getItem(position));
            }
            uAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            int checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
            if (checkedItems==1){
                mode.setTitle(String.valueOf(checkedItems) + getString(R.string.selected));
            } else {
                mode.setTitle(String.valueOf(checkedItems) + getString(R.string.more_selected));
            }

        }
    });
    uAdapter= new UsersAdapter(this, User.class, R.layout.one_user, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users"));
    listView.setAdapter(uAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int position, long arg3) {
            selectedPosition = position;
            final ListView list = (ListView) arg0;
            list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            list.setItemChecked(position, true);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I was supposing that with this code i can take position for each values of adminToAdd ArrayList. Then, i use it for set another database child called "Admins". The way:

```
@Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_admin_add:

                    for (User newAdmin : adminToAdd) {
                        DatabaseReference admin_node= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot().child("Admins");
                        admin_node.push().setValue(idAdminToAdd);
                        Toast.makeText(UsersList.this,getString(R.string.admin_added),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    uAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mode.finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

No way, i can selelect whatever element of the listview, but i get always the first one. Any help will be appreciated.

Update: This is the Listener i use for get the idAdminToAdd value:

```
DatabaseReference adminDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot().child("Users");
    adminDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                idAdminToAdd = childSnapshot.getKey();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the element of ListView on which the user has clicked you need to use the following line of code:

```
String s = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
Log("TAG", s);
```

Comment: I have to put this on "OnLongClickListener"? And what i can do with string s?

Comment: Everything you want. It represents the value of type String of the ListView element on which the user has long clicked. Does it log in the logcat the value of corresponding item?

Comment: I see. But the goal of the listview is to select one user and take its Uid value trought ValueEventListener, and store it in idAdminToAdd. I'm sorry that in the question is not so clear. With the code i made, the value rapresent really 2 Uid, but whatever element i choose i got always only one of them. Non i'm wandering if it's easier to do this : admin_node.push().setValue(s).

Answer (score 0):

Well, i founded it by myself. As usual, most of errors was a consequence of bad tutorials. First of all, i wanted to add items to "Admin" database using a Contextual Action Bar and in the meanwhile add more items in the same tame. This behavior is described in "setMultiChoiceModeListener()".

The solution to the problem is to get the correct position on the adapter based on "int position", and so get the corresponding index given from an ArrayList that contains all the items displayed.

Code:

```
 final ArrayList<String> adminList = new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference adminRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    adminRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot users : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                adminList.add(users.getKey());
            }

            listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.admin_activity_menu, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem menuItem) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.menu_admin_add:
                            DatabaseReference admin_node= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot().child("Admins");
                            admin_node.push().setValue(adminList.get(selectedPosition));
                            Toast.makeText(UsersList.this,getString(R.string.admin_added),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            uAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            mode.finish();
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                                      long id, boolean checked) {
                    selectedPosition = position;
                    uAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    int checkedItems = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
                    if (checkedItems==1){
                        mode.setTitle(String.valueOf(checkedItems) +" "+ getString(R.string.selected));
                    } else {
                        mode.setTitle(String.valueOf(checkedItems) +" "+ getString(R.string.more_selected));
                    }
                }
            });
```

As you see, first i added all the items in the adminList array, then setted the value of "Admin" with the element contained in the index given from "selectedPosition".